# How to add tooltip to a drop down/combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, tooltip

I have to implement the tooltip feature for drop down. Also, tooltip will not be any static text, it should be the selected value of drop down.
How can i do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the soultion:

Just in case you wanted to know how i did that:-

```
jQuery('#myDropDownID').hover(function(e){
                var tipX = e.pageX + 12;
                var tipY = e.pageY + 12; 
                jQuery("body").append("<div id='myTooltip' class='portal-tool-tip' style='position: absolute; z-index: 100; display: none;'>" + jQuery("OPTION:selected", this).text()  + "</div>");
                if(jQuery.browser.msie) var tipWidth = jQuery("#myTooltip").outerWidth(true)
                else var tipWidth = jQuery("#myTooltip").width()
                jQuery("#myTooltip").width(tipWidth);
                jQuery("#myTooltip").css("left", tipX).css("top", tipY).fadeIn("medium");
            }, function(){
                jQuery("#myTooltip").remove();              
            }).mousemove(function(e){
                var tipX = e.pageX + 12;
                var tipY = e.pageY + 12;
                var tipWidth = jQuery("#myTooltip").outerWidth(true);
                var tipHeight = jQuery("#myTooltip").outerHeight(true);
                if(tipX + tipWidth > jQuery(window).scrollLeft() + jQuery(window).width()) tipX = e.pageX - tipWidth;
                if(jQuery(window).height()+jQuery(window).scrollTop() < tipY + tipHeight) tipY = e.pageY - tipHeight;
                jQuery("#myTooltip").css("left", tipX).css("top", tipY).fadeIn("medium");
            });
```

See here:
http://jsbin.com/owoka

Answer (score 1):

JAVASCRIPT AND JQUERY.

You were specific about tooltip for only the selected value for all the dropdowns in the page at once..

```
<script language="javascript">
function dropDwnToolTips() {
var drpdwnlst = document.getElementsByTagName("Select");
    for(i=0;i<drpdwnlst.length;i++){
        drpdwnlst[i].title = drpdwnlst[i].options[drpdwnlst[i].selectedIndex].text;
    }
}
</script>
```

In the below code i am adding tooltip for all the values in the drop down as well as the selected value.
This in java script as well and that too for all the dropdowns in the page at once.

```
<script language="javascript">
function dropDwnToolTips() {
  var drpdwnlst = document.getElementsByTagName("Select");
  for(i=0;i<drpdwnlst.length;i++){
      for(j=0;j<drpdwnlst[i].length;j++){
          drpdwnlst[i][j].title = drpdwnlst[i].options[j].text;
      }
      drpdwnlst[i].title = drpdwnlst[i].options[drpdwnlst[i].selectedIndex].text;
  }
}
</script>
```

for either function, Do the below to trigger it.

```
<body onload="dropDwnToolTips()">
...
</body>
```

or,

```
<script language="javascript">
window.onload=function() {
    ... script code goes here...
}
```

or if you are using dojo,

```
<script language="javascript">
dojo.ready(function() {
    ... script code goes here...
});
```

or

jQuery makes the whole script even simpler..

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("select").each(function() { 
        var s = this; 
        for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) 
            s.options[i].title = s.options[i].text; 
        if (s.selectedIndex > -1) 
            s.onmousemove = function() { s.title = s.options[s.selectedIndex].text; }; 
    }); 
});
```

I would suggest you to use the function on the onChange event of the dropdown instead of document ready event.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the dropdown in javascript as a div. Once you do that, you can add the tooltips using something like: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Comment: is there any other approach instead of creating the div for drop down

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
selectElement.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  selectElement.title = selectElement.value;
});
```

Comment: Alsciende, this is not what i was expecting. :). Tooltip must be displayed in nice way. The title shown by browser doesn't look good. Tooltip: http://dev.mariusilie.net/content/simple-tooltip-jquery-plugin

Comment: Well, I guess you can call you own tooltip-api instead of ".title".

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://webneed.blogspot.com/2009/12/how-to-add-tooltips-to-dropdownlist.html